# Intermittent Clutch Bite - 2018 Chevy Cruze LT RS Manual Trans

Tags: chevrolet, transmission, clutch, intermittent-problems, master-cylinder

**Background**: As included in the title, I've recently acquired a 2018 chevy cruze LT RS with a manual trans. It's got 42k miles on it.

**Problem**: On normal operation, the clutch will start to grab about 1/3 of the way up, and the gear will totally engage around 2/3 of the way up. However, every once in a while I will notice that upon depressing the clutch, it gives much easier than normal, and after shifting into gear and releasing the clutch, it will grab nearly instantaneously (maybe 5%-10% off the 'floor') with a much smaller 'grab' zone. I'm not sure it's related, but I have noticed this happen more consistently after downshifting from 3rd to 2nd, which is fine, then when I shift back up to 3rd it has happened. I've also noticed that this occurs more frequently when I shift from 1st to 2nd during a heavy acceleration, or from 2nd to 3rd doing the same (i.e. starting shift from around 4.5k RPMs). However, it has also happened during totally casual driving as well.

Any advice is greatly appreciated!